# Gmaps runs fine and shows in notebook but not in HTML

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

my Gmaps code runs fine in my Jupyter notebook and the map shows, but when I save it into an HTML file, only the code is there without the map output.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

I made a simple reproducible example below

```
import gmaps
import pandas as pd

arr = pd.DataFrame([[40.70772,-74.012963],[40.740184,-73.986363],[40.72635,-73.988386]])
arr.columns = ["Latitude","Longitude"]

gmaps.configure(api_key = 'my key')  #my API key
m1 = gmaps.Map(center = (40.730610, -73.935242), zoom_level = 20)
m1.add_layer(gmaps.heatmap_layer(arr))
m1
```

This is my code in jupyter and it produces the following when I run in, it looks like this
[Jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGnWp.png)
but when I save it as an HTML the map doesn't appear as you can see here
[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZA5zj.png)

Comment: Any code example? Please consider to provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and ease to answer it.

Comment: @dboy hey I added a short example! thanks